# What is the easiest way to find out what's on topic for a given Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion

I sometimes encounter people telling me my question is off-topic on a given Stack Exchange site and that I should post on a different site.

How can I quickly find out what's on topic for either site and decide where to post?

Comment: Easiest is to check (and acknowledge) [everything here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: [Post a question on MSE tagged "site-recommendation"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-recommendation)

Comment: Other than just posting it and await the comments? That's usually very quick ;)

Comment: Thanks everyone! I think the /help/on-topic link is what I'm after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every Stack Exchange site has it's own section in the help center, to explain which questions are on topic and what can be asked. Some examples:

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
- [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- ...

You may notice these are all different. So please always check the specific help center before asking a question on a SE site you're not familiar yet.

Comment: Is there a list of all 'on-topic' pages somewhere, so OP doesn't have to browse each and every SE page? ("[3D Printing](http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) .. nope .. [Academia](http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) .. nope .. [Amateur Radio](http://ham.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) ...")

Comment: @RadLexus Not that I'm aware of such list.